# Extract sequence of text without tags with Scrapy

Tags: xpath, scrapy

Assuming the following pattern:

```
<div>
  <a href="#">Option 1</a>
  Option 1 Description
  <a href="#">Option 2</a>
  Option 2 Description
  <a href="#">Option 3</a>
  Option 3 Description
  ...
</div>
```

I would like to obtain the text within each `a` tag and the following *description text* (which is not wrapped in tags).

What would be the best way to do so?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have figured out a possible solution:

```python
a_tags = response.css('div a')

for a in a_tags:
    command = a.xpath('text()').get()
    description = a.xpath('./following-sibling::text()[1]').get().strip()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make it in one xpath-selector: `//div/a/following-sibling::text()` for descriptions and just `div ::text` for all the texts.

Check this example from `scrapy shell`:

```
In [1]: txt = """<div>
   ...:   <a href="#">Option 1</a>
   ...:   Option 1 Description
   ...:   <a href="#">Option 2</a>
   ...:   Option 2 Description
   ...:   <a href="#">Option 3</a>
   ...:   Option 3 Description
   ...: </div>"""

In [2]: from scrapy import Selector

In [3]: sel = Selector(text=txt)

In [4]: sel.xpath("//div/a/following-sibling::text()").extract()
Out[4]: 
[u'\n  Option 1 Description\n  ',
 u'\n  Option 2 Description\n  ',
 u'\n  Option 3 Description\n']

In [5]: sel.css('div ::text').extract()
Out[5]: 
[u'\n  ',
 u'Option 1',
 u'\n  Option 1 Description\n  ',
 u'Option 2',
 u'\n  Option 2 Description\n  ',
 u'Option 3',
 u'\n  Option 3 Description\n']
```